# Rails app can't find my Gem's javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I wrote a [gem](https://github.com/jnwelzel/slide-down-alerts-rails) and installed it in my Rails app, including the following [configuration](https://gist.github.com/jnwelzel/5250456) inside the app. Problem is that the Rails app does not find the Gem's Javascript files and Sprockets gives me errors such as "Sprockets::FileNotFound". Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Solved using accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gem must contain an engine class which inherits from `Rails::Engine` for Sprockets to include it in its scan path.
See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems